# how to count the occurance of multidimentional arrays of string?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

```
[['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'], ['Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)', 'Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St'], ['Franklin St & Monroe St', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave'], ['State St & Kinzie St', 'Wells St & Polk St'], ['Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Dayton St & North Ave', 'Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave'], ['Wilton Ave & Diversey Pkwy', 'Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave'], ['Canal St & Madison St', 'LaSalle St & Illinois St'], ['Theater on the Lake', 'Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy'], ['Halsted St & Maxwell St', 'Halsted St & 18th St'], ['Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter']]
```

This is my list of list. How do i count the occurance of `['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)']`

the output should be

```
  ['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)']  : 1
  ['Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'] : 2
etc
```

Comment: Please give a clearer description of your question.

Answer (score 1):

U need to do something like this:-

```
super = [['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'], ['Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)', 'Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St'], ['Franklin St & Monroe St', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave'], ['State St & Kinzie St', 'Wells St & Polk St'], ['Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Dayton St & North Ave', 'Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave'], ['Wilton Ave & Diversey Pkwy', 'Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave'], ['Canal St & Madison St', 'LaSalle St & Illinois St'], ['Theater on the Lake', 'Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy'], ['Halsted St & Maxwell St', 'Halsted St & 18th St'], ['Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter']]
search = ['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)']
print(super.count(search))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` feature of list

```
l = [['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'], ['Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)', 'Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St'], ['Franklin St & Monroe St', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave'], ['State St & Kinzie St', 'Wells St & Polk St'], ['Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Dayton St & North Ave', 'Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave'], ['Wilton Ave & Diversey Pkwy', 'Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave'], ['Canal St & Madison St', 'LaSalle St & Illinois St'], ['Theater on the Lake', 'Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy'], ['Halsted St & Maxwell St', 'Halsted St & 18th St'], ['Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter']]
for i in l:
    c = l.count(i)
    print(i, '--->' ,c)
```

Comment: no need to add `if i in l` because you are iterating over list meaning that should be in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` in python standard module `collections`. However, it does not allow keys as `list`, so you have to convert it to `tuple`.

```
from collections import Counter

a_list = [['Canal St & Taylor St', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'], ['Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)', 'Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St'], ['Franklin St & Monroe St', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave'], ['State St & Kinzie St', 'Wells St & Polk St'], ['Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl', 'Clinton St & Tilden St'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)'], ['Dayton St & North Ave', 'Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave'], ['Wilton Ave & Diversey Pkwy', 'Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave'], ['Canal St & Madison St', 'LaSalle St & Illinois St'], ['Theater on the Lake', 'Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy'], ['Halsted St & Maxwell St', 'Halsted St & 18th St'], ['Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter']]

counter = Counter([tuple(item) for item in a_list])
dict(counter)

# {('Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St'): 1,('Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave'): 1, ... }
```